# Generating PHP Passwords for a database without PHP

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, sqlite, passwords

PHP includes a pair of functions to generate and validate passwords, using, I believe, BCrypt. This makes it easy to use password hashes stored in a database table.

The only problem with that is that it makes it difficult to manually add a password using a normal database client. Normally I end up creating a small PHP script just to add or edit a user row.

The question is: are there functions or libraries which can be added to the various databases which implement the same hashing as PHP? Failing that, are there any standalone applications?

This question relates to the popular Web databases, PotgreSQL, MySQL and SQLite. Personally I use Mac and Linux for web development, but I often teach on Windows.

Comment: You're asking for a *resource*? That would be *off-topic* here on SO. If your question relates to programming, it's unclear to me. You can use the same cryptography methods through different programming languages, if that is your question. You'll have to write your own way of doing it though, **be carefull with that!!**.

Comment: do you mean native mysql function equivalents for password_hash and password_verify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there aren't MySQL functions available to emulate `password_hash()` or `password_verify()`. There's a good performance reason for that: they use many rounds of expensive hashing. The point is to slow down cybercreeps trying to guess passwords.  In most web systems, the DBMS is the scarce resource, so you don't want to burden it with half-second cpu-grinding computations.  Better to put that workload on a web server you can duplicate in a load-balancer pool.

Your approach of building a password-reset function in a small (and secure) php program is the right one.  You may also want to build a self-service password recovery function. WordPress has a good one: it sends your user an email containing a one-time-use link (a link with a [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) in it) to a page prompting for a new password.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suppose I can easily write a PHP script and use it as an Ajax service.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL comes with a handy third part extension named [pg_crypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html). It adds hash functions and symmetric key encryption algorithms.

I prefer to use the database for password encryption & validation in a web environment for several reasons:

1. The `crypt` method from pgcrypto is more flexible than any PHP method. It is possible to migrate the hash algorithm and have two encryption algorithm at the same time in the database. This makes possible to have a strongest encryption when passwords are renewed.
2. From a performance perspective, web servers are often loaded whereas the database has a lot of small read only queries using indexes. It is also possible to distribute the authentication queries over multiple secondary database servers.
3. From a security perspective, the web severs open to the wild internet use a database user not allowed to read the `user.account` table where the emails, hashed password lie. To authenticate the users, applications must use a `SECURITY DEFINER` SQL function that returns user account information only if the provided password is correct. This ensures an attacker gaining access to the database from any of the web servers cannot access the account informations nor write in the database.